# Django error faced whil making the project list is not getting displayed

Tags: django, list, web, python-3.8

I am creating this tab in Django and wants that it will display the list of 10 youtube searches but it is showing only one below is the code for my view.py youtube method and below that is my template section can someone help me I want the list of my top ten searches will be displayed ut it is only showing 1 I don't know why

```
def youtube(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        form = DashboardForm(request.POST)
        text = request.POST['text']
        video = VideosSearch(text,limit=10)
        result_list=[]
        for i in video.result()['result']:
            result_dict={
                'input':text,
                'title':i['title'],
                'duration':i['duration'],
                'thumbnail':i['thumbnails'][0]['url'],
                'channel':i['channel']['name'],
                'link':i['link'],
                'views':i['viewCount']['short'],
                'published':i['publishedTime']
            }
        desc=''
        if i['descriptionSnippet']:
            for j in i['descriptionSnippet']:
                desc+=j['text']
        result_dict['description']=desc
        result_list.append(result_dict)
        context={'form':form,
        'results':result_list}
        return render(request,'dashboard/youtube.html',context)
    else:
        form =DashboardForm()
    context={'form':form}
    return render(request,'dashboard/youtube.html',context)


{% extends 'dashboard/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<section class='text-center container'>
    <h2>Search Videos in Youtube</h2>
    <p>search videos and select any video to open in youtube</p>
    <form action="" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{form}}
        <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form><br>
    {% for result in results %}
    <a href="{{result.link}}" target="_blank">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="{{result.thumbnail}}" alt="">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <h3 class="p-0 m-0">{{result.title}}</h3>
                        <b>
                            <u>
                                <h5 class="p-0 m-0">{{result.channel}}</h5>
                            </u>
                        </b>
                        <h6 class="p-0 m-1">{{result.description}}</h6>
                        <b>
                            <h6 class="ml-0 mt-3">{{result.duration}}</h6>
                            <h6 class="ml-0 mt-1">{{result.views}}</h6>
                            <h6 class="ml-0 mt-1">{{result.published}}</h6>
                        </b>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    {% endfor %}
    <br>
</section>

{% end block content %}
```

Comment: print the following in the console in your `views.py`: `len(result_list)`. And what library are you using to search the videos. Because it is odd to see the method name `video.result()` without a `s` while it is for a list.

Comment: Look's like you are appending result_dict  into result_list outside the FOR loop.
The result must consist of only 1 object that would be the last object from the array

Comment: yeah  problem is solved thank you guys it was the indentation problem thanks for helping guys